# Android saving socket connection in service

Tags: android, sockets, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I want to listen to certain events like incoming phone call,SMS etc in android and send it via Bluetooth.I have tried to setup the broadcast receiver for the events and its working fine.But how do i  pass the data from broadcast receiver to the service and also create and preserve the socket connection in the service.One more problem is that the onCreate() function in my service is being called every time I start the activity.